# Spring with X509 Authentication is not prompting for certificates

Tags: spring, x509

I'm trying to upgrade our Spring-based application from JDK 8 to 17, and Spring 3 to 6

However, it has stopped requesting certificates from the client on load, and as such can't properly authenticate or fetch the username

Security context:

```xml
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern='/' access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern='/**' access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern='/general' access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="ntlmFilter" />
    <x509 />
</http>

<beans:bean id="ntlmFilter" class="mil.serena.subject.web.security.SubjectPreAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="ntlmAuthentication" ref="ntlmAuthentication" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="ntlmAuthentication" class="mil.serena.subject.web.security.NTLMAuthentication">
    <beans:property name="principalRequestHeader" value="Authorization" /> <!-- NTLM request.getHeader("Authorization") -->
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="preauthAuthProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="preauthAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService">
        <beans:bean id="userDetailsServiceWrapper" class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper">
            <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="customUserDetailsService" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="mil.serena.subject.web.security.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />

<beans:bean id="http403EntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint" />

<beans:bean id="mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector" />
```

`NTLMAuthentication` is checking the `session_user` attribute if the `Authorization` attribute is not set and otherwise grabbing username through the request's `remoteUser`, and `SubjectPreAuthenticationFilter` is running that for the user name and setting it as an attribute to be grabbed by other parts of the program

`UserDetailsServiceImpl` was already implemented by the configs, but it seems to be only logging the username information before passing back a standard UserDetails object

Additionally, the `web.xml` is already implementing a `DelegatingFilterProxy`